# Mongoengine Database cannot change Database

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

At our company we have a standard connection string format to connect to a mongodb database, for example:
`mongodb://<some_user>:<some_password>@<some_host>.mongodb.net/admin&authSource=admin`

When i register the connection with mongoengine
`connect(host=<connection_string>, db="my_db")` the db to be accessed remains `admin` and `my_db` is not used. What I need is to override the database given by our standard connection string with the database I actually want to use.
I tried to use the method `switch_db` but as the method needs to be using a db-alias of a predefined connection, this is also not possible.

I know, a solution would be to change the connection-string by chaning the initial database name. But I need a solution to be able to dynamically change database name without changing the uri.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your application works, but some time ago I had a similar problem.

I don't know what technology your company uses, but in my case it's FastAPI, and well, I use a function as a dependency, and it returns a default value.

```py
def get_db():
  return 'admin'

@router.get('/')
def connect(db_type=Depends(get_db)):
   return mongoengine.connect(host=f'mongodb://<some_user>:<some_password>@<some_host>.mongodb.net/admin&authSource=admin', db=db_type)
```

And if you are like, changing to my_db when testing, or something like that,
you use:

```py
def get_new_db():
  returns 'my_db'

app.dependency_overrides[get_db]=get_new_db
```

And after you use the DB as you want in the functionality, just run (so that you return to the default value of admin).

```py
app.dependency_overrides.clear()
```